# Не сохраняются настройки

Tags: c#

```
private void цвестToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        colorDialog1.ShowDialog();
        Settings.Default.mecolor = colorDialog1.Color;
        menuStrip1.BackColor = Settings.Default.mecolor;
        главнаяСтраницаToolStripMenuItem.BackColor = Settings.Default.mecolor;
        Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Пояснения:

- `mecolor` - это настройка, которая отвечает за цвета на форме
- `menuStrip1` - он и есть `menuStrip1`
- `главнаяСтраницаToolStripMenuItem` - это кнопка в меню в программе

Вот у меня такой код... настройки не сохраняются :( Что делать и как исправить?

Comment: У меня этот код работает и сетинги сохраняются, при условии, конечно, что имя созданного вами файла и класса для хранения именно Settings

Comment: Не знаю.... у меня должны цвета формы сохранятся, а они не сохраняются :(

Comment: Как вы определяете, что они не сохраняются?

Comment: У меня изначальный цвет формы Зеленый, я изменил его на Красный, и после этого сохранил настройки и потом запускаю по новой, и цвет не красный, а зеленый.

Answer (score 2):

После сохранения пользовательской настройки в исходном файле значение не изменится, если вы его снова откроете, так как в нем отображается "дефолтное" значение. Но при последующих программных обращениях вы получите сохраненное значение. Вероятней всего при загрузке приложения вы не меняете ваши настройки для нужных компонентов системы.

Comment: ПС убил бы за русскоязычное именование контролов =)